# Is tcpdump reliable? Why there are so many packets with length 0?

Tags: tcpdump

I am using tcpdump to collect packet data through wlan0. But I find many packets with length of 0 like following picture shows. Well, length 0 packets... Is tcpdump reliable or I have missed something? 
[image]

Comment: What is the *full* output of tcpdump, going all the way to the end of the line?  And what does `tcpdump -h` print?  Assuming those are valid packets, the length shouldn't be 0 (if the total length field of an IPv4 packet is less than 20, that's not a valid IPv4 packet), but there might be something else happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, those are TCP packets, and that's the *TCP payload* length.  That *can* be zero, if a TCP packet is just acknowledging data sent by the other side of the connection, and not sending any data.

For example, the next to the last packet is from 121.186.151.61.dial.xw.sh.dynamic.163data.com.cn, port 80 (that's the ".http" at the end - it's not part of the domain name, it's an indication that it's from port 80) to android-1b46862a4910306b, port 53876, with 16 bytes of data.  The last packet is android-1b46862a4910306b sending an ACK to 121.186.151.61.dial.xw.sh.dynamic.163data.com, probably acknowledging the previous 16 bytes.

The other zero-length packets in your sample output are TCP FIN packets, which don't have to have data in them (the host sending it is just saying "I don't have any more data to send you, and never will have any more data to send you on this connection - I'm done"), and TCP RST packets, which are just forcibly shutting down the connection and also don't have to have data in them.

Comment: Thanks Guy,  now I got it :)